# VisitId between (different) date range for each user

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

For each `fullvisitorId`, i'm trying to get all `visitId` between date_1 and date_2. which is of-course differ for each user.

Can anyone give any pointers how I can go about doing this?

for example:

- user_1: i'd like all visitId between 1st & 20th June
- user_2: i'd like all visitId between 12th & 27th June
  ... and so son

date_1 and date_2 correspond to important actions (`Event` hits) they took on the site. Download Trial & Purchase

Thanks in advance for any leads in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of solving this is using [analytical functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions). As an example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  select '1' as user, '1' as visitid, '20170520' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('event1' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '1' as user, '2' as visitid, '20170521' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '1' as user, '3' as visitid, '20170522' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('event2' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '1' as user, '4' as visitid, '20170523' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL

  select '2' as user, '1' as visitid, '20170520' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('event1' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '2' as user, '2' as visitid, '20170521' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('event2' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '2' as user, '3' as visitid, '20170522' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits union all

  select '3' as user, '1' as visitid, '20170520' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('event1' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '3' as user, '2' as visitid, '20170521' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits UNION ALL
  select '3' as user, '3' as visitid, '20170522' as date, ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, eventInfo STRUCT<eventCategory STRING> >> [STRUCT(1 as hitNumber, STRUCT('' as eventCategory) as eventInfo)] hits
)

SELECT
  user,
  visitid,
  date
FROM(
  SELECT 
    user,
    visitid,
    date,
    MIN(CASE WHEN hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'event1' THEN date END) OVER(PARTITION BY user) min_date,
MAX(CASE WHEN hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'event2' THEN date END) OVER(PARTITION BY user) max_date
FROM data,
UNNEST(hits) hits
)
WHERE date BETWEEN min_date AND max_date
```

Where `data` is a simulation of your *ga_sessions* data (I named 'fullvisitorid' as 'user').

This makes the assumption that a given user can have distinct events for date 1 and date 2 (so it's taking the `MIN` and `MAX` respectively) and it assumes that you are saving the event in the `eventCategory` field (given that your event of "Download" and "Purchase" are defined in the session level, I recommend you use the [customDimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) field instead of the `hits.eventInfo.eventCategory` one).

Other than analytical functions, you can also work with [ARRAYs and STRUCTs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#arrays_and_structs) of the Standard SQL version:

```
SELECT
  user,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT visitid, date FROM UNNEST(user_data) WHERE date BETWEEN min_date AND max_date) user_data
FROM(
  SELECT 
    user,
    ARRAY_AGG((SELECT AS STRUCT visitid, date)) user_data,
    MIN(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) hits WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'event1') then date END) min_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) hits WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'event2') THEN date END) max_date
FROM data
GROUP BY user
)
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT visitid, date FROM UNNEST(user_data) WHERE date BETWEEN min_date AND max_date)) > 0
```

If the assumptions I made are not aligned with your data you can adapt these techniques to query for what you want. You can also use the simulated data for testing purposes (as well as adapting it to better suit your dataset).

Comment: Thanks @Will This helped ! :)